# How to show filtered table view in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, uipageviewcontroller

I have 2 `tableView`s at the moment. 
One is a basic `tableView` which shows cells and if selected, it goes into a detailed `viewController`.

I created a new `viewController` to create a `filtered` page view. I populate my page view with a plist. I managed to create a filter but don't know how to proceed from here.

This is what I have:

```
- (IBAction)ingredientsAddButton:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    int j=0;
    onemsiz.text=ingredientTextField.text;
    ingredientText=onemsiz.text;
    NSLog(ingredientText);
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recipes" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *arrayOfPlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if (arrayOfPlist==NULL) {

    }else {
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) { 
            // i currently have 4 element is plist.
            NSString *strCurrentRecipeIngredients = [[arrayOfPlist objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"recipeIngredients"];
            NSString *strCurrentRecipeName = [[arrayOfPlist objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"recipeName"];
            //NSLog(@"%d. Loop \n", i+1);
            if([strCurrentRecipeIngredients rangeOfString:(@"%@",ingredientText)].location!=NSNotFound) {
                NSLog(@"%@ contains %@ ",strCurrentRecipeName, ingredientText);
                NSLog(ingredientText);
                NSLog(strCurrentRecipeIngredients);
                j++;
            }else {
                NSLog(@"Not found");
                NSLog(ingredientText);
                NSLog(strCurrentRecipeIngredients);
            }

            if (ingredientText==NULL) {
                NSLog(@"empty input");
            }else {

            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",j);
}
```

My first problem is how can I show the results in a `tableView`?

Answer (score 0):

You create a [table view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and then create and assign its [data source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). If data in one of the table view needs to be changed when it is already displayed, the easy way to force it to update is call `[tableView reloadData];`