# How to create table view controller from filtered arrays in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

I have 2 tableviews at the moment. One is the basic which shows each cells and if selected it navigates to a detail view controller.

I created a new ViewController to create a filtered page view. I populate my page view with plist. I managed to create a filter but i don't know how to proceed from here.

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)ingredientsAddButton:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    int j=0;
    onemsiz.text=ingredientTextField.text;
    ingredientText=onemsiz.text;
    NSLog(ingredientText);
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recipes" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *arrayOfPlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if (arrayOfPlist==NULL) {

    }else {
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) { 
            // i currently have 4 element is plist.
            NSString *strCurrentRecipeIngredients = [[arrayOfPlist objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"recipeIngredients"];
            NSString *strCurrentRecipeName = [[arrayOfPlist objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"recipeName"];
            //NSLog(@"%d. Loop \n", i+1);
            if([strCurrentRecipeIngredients rangeOfString:(@"%@",ingredientText)].location!=NSNotFound)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@ contains %@ ",strCurrentRecipeName, ingredientText);
                NSLog(ingredientText);
                NSLog(strCurrentRecipeIngredients);
                j++;
            }else {
                NSLog(@"Not found");
                NSLog(ingredientText);
                NSLog(strCurrentRecipeIngredients);
            }
            if (ingredientText==NULL) {
                NSLog(@"empty input");
            }else {

            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",j);
}
```

My first problem is how can I show the results in a table view? I can give some screenshots if you want.

Comment: It is 100% duplicate of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306047/how-to-show-filtered-table-view-in-ios and it is formulated just as bad as the previous one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is very poorly formulated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add bool ivar which will tell when you need to show the filtered array and new array which will show filtered data:

```
BOOL isShowFilteredData;
NSArray *filteredData;
```

In init or viewDidLoad initialize bool to false (you don't want to show all data);

```
isShowFilteredData = NO;
```

You have to change the datasource/delegate method to use right data:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return isShowFilteredData ? isShowFilteredData.count : myDataArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //configure cell, etc..
    //your code 
    if (isShowFilteredData) 
    {
         // show filtered data
         id obj = filteredData[indexPath.row];
         // do something with result
    }
    else
    {
        // show all data
    }
}
```

Now when you want to show filtered data just change ivar to true, initialise filteredData array and fill it in with the data you want to show and call reloadData:

```
isShowFilteredData = YES;
filteredData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:.....];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

but if you want to show all data do:

```
isShowFilteredData = NO;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

This is just one of the solution you can use.